# Center Form on Startup

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on a web browser in C#, so I made a splash screen for it. However, the splash screen isn't located at the center of the screen when it starts up. So is there a way to center the form on startup?

[image]

Working code:

```
public splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }
```

Comment: This is actually not the best place to store the GUI customization. Consider to use Form1.Designer.cs instead.

Comment: splash.Designer.cs most likely in your case

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;`

[MSDN FormStartPosition Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx)

Comment: Great. Please be sure to accept the answers you find most helpful (click in the empty checkmark to turn it green and accept it.)

Answer (score 6):

```
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to do it from GUI and you work with Visual Studio, then use these steps:
1. Open your form in the form designer 
2. Navigate to form properties 
3. Change the "StartPosition" to "CenterScreen"

Comment: I can't believe I actually missed that! It was in the properties panel all along.

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        //Method 1. center at initilization
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        //Method 2. The manual way
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - this.Height)/2;
        this.Left = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - this.Width)/2;

    }
  }
}
```